# Unable to find files copied from pc to internal storage

Tags: file-system, file-management, media-files, es-file-explorer

I have copied files (around  2GB) to my android phone's internal storage from my friend's pc. But I'm unable to find those files either by using file manager(root) or from my pc. 
When I checked my phone's memory usage, it confirms the presence of those files. 
Is there any way to retrieve those files.

Comment: They should be there, where you copied them to. I suppose in `/sdcard` or `/extSdCard` / `/external_sd`. You may also try searching for the file name and find it that way.

Comment: There is an app called 'Diskusage' for android. It will scan your storage, will tell you Folder wise what's taking your space and you can explore them. It should see your file unless they are corrupted and not mapped in MFT of filesystem. Alternatively, 'ES File Explorer' App also has a scanning feature but I like Diskusage more. Give it a try after Rebooting your phone.